# Vulnerability fix for Apache Commons Text with wso2 carbon libraries

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am looking out for suggestions on the recent vulnerability(https://blogs.apache.org/security/entry/cve-2022-42889) which is also coming from the wso2 IS 5.11 binary downloaded from(https://github.com/wso2/product-is/releases/tag/v5.11.0) and the carbon libraries we are using in custom plugins like:

```
<groupId>org.wso2.carbon.identity.framework</groupId><artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt</artifactId>
<version>5.18.187</version>

<groupId>org.wso2.carbon.identity.framework</groupId>
<artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework</artifactId>
<version>5.18.187</version>

<groupId>org.wso2.carbon.identity.framework</groupId>
<artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.identity.provisioning</artifactId>
<version>5.18.187</version>
```

As there any upgrades to these which is compatible with wso2 IS v5.11?

Answer (score 1):

From wso2 advisories, it is mentioned that the vulnerability has no impact on the products [1] since the preconditions are not met and the team promises of fixing the vulnerable versions and (paid) customers will be able to obtain it through their security update once it is available. Along with this effort, the public fix will be done for the current public branch and *will be available* if you build the product-is from the repository. The timeline for the public fix is yet to be known.

And the suggested upgrade would be to 1.10.0 of Apache Commons Text library for 5.11.0.

This library comes to Identity server 5.11 pack mainly through **Forget me** tool. And in the latest release (wso2is-6.0.0), forget me tool has been externalized[2] which could be used in the product on demand.

**Refer**:

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/Security/CVE-2022-42889

[2] https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/deploy/remove-references-to-deleted-user-identities/#building-the-identity-anonymization-tool